# USB boot will not boot even though selected in BIOS

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I am trying to figure out how to get my computer to boot from USB. Here's the issue. In BIOS I have put the USB on top, CD second and hard-drive third for boot order. But it will not boot from the USB. When I press F12 it doesn't show the USB at all, just the CD and hard-drive. When I am in the operating system (Ubuntu) and before that Windows 10, the USBs work fine. So I know that the USB connectors are connected inside my computer. I am completely baffled and befuddled. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Is the USB well made to boot?

Comment: test the usb-thumb-drive in another machine to ensure its bootable

Comment: Yes, I checked the USB on my wife's computer and it worked just fine, it's my computer.

Comment: In order for modern UEFI systems to boot a USB it must be GPT partitioned and contain an ESP with an EFI application. If the BIOS doesn't find all that it doesn't think the USB is bootable.

Comment: What tools did you use to make the USB into a bootable drive?

Comment: Many computers see a USB drive as just another hard drive, try setting the USB drive as the first hard drive in BIOS.